# Google App Engine (Python) slow ancestor queries

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using appstats to debug some important queries in our app. One thing I noticed is that for a particular entity kind, an ancestor query is many times slower than a non-ancestor query.

When I go from:

```
q = Entity.query(ancestor=ancestor_key)
q = q.filter(Entity.field == 'foo')
return q.fetch(10)
```

to:

```
q = Entity.query()
q = q.filter(Entity.field == 'foo')
return q.fetch(10)
```

In the development environment, the first query *always* takes more than 500 ms and often above 1 second while the second one takes 20-100 ms. All the right indexes are in place and nothing else is running at the same time as the queries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dev_appserver is an emulation of the real thing. It can't behave in the same way. Don't worry about stuff like this unless it's also a problem when deployed.

Comment: It seems to also be a problem when deployed, but I'll run some more tests.

Comment: It seems that you might be right about the emulation part. I'll probably be back with a similar question sometime :-) For now, I'll accept this answer.